# PayPal TimeOut - DoExpressCheckoutPayment

Tags: paypal

We are using PayPal on a faily large website, integration went well with all code helpers from the integration wizard. Now we had processed a number of transactions in the first day of putting this live but a small percentage (5%) essentially had there transaction processed by PayPal but our system recieved a TimeOut. I believe this happens at the point where we submit the "DoExpressCheckoutPayment" Method. and because of this the system cannot tell if the payment has been complete or not.

This is a real tough one, as the website has a live currency that we need to update so paypal taking the money but the system not updating is not acceptable.

I'm interested to know if this is a common problem and how we should go about handeling it. I'm doing my best to re-create the issue but cannot at this time.

This looks like a similar problem - https://www.x.com/thread/45136

Any help would be appriciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into this in more depth, retry logic is not a good idea as the TimeOut is due to the response (So paypal has most likly credited the account).

Instant Payment Notification (IPN) seems to be the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Add retry logic to your application.  This is a common way of handling this problem.

Comment: So re-try on timeout? Also, whats the best way to simulate a timeout!?

Comment: @Pino, Yes, depends on how your abstractions look.  Whatever reports that a payment transaction failed should be made aware of the possibility of a timeout.

Comment: And how can one simulate this in development?

Comment: @Pino, Without being familiar with your code I can't tell you.  You can't tell PayPal to return a timeout but you certainly mock, stub and fake that result.